# How can I generate a pseudo-random list of 1s and -1s?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate a pseudo-random list of 10 numbers seeded by a seed. I only want that this list has 1s and -1s and the probability of each one was 0.5.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.randint(2, size=(10,))
```

I don´t get a distribution of 1s and -1s, only of 1s and 0s... and I don´t know
if the probability of each number is 1/2.

Any clue?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice

Answer (score 1):

As @jtbandes said, [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice) function will help:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.choice([-1,1], size=(10,))
```

Comment: OK, the range is correct but this is not an uniform distribution, is it? Because I need that -1 and 1 have almost the same probability :S

Comment: It is indeed a uniform distribution as I've omitted the last parameter `p` (quoting docs: "If not given the sample assumes a uniform distribution over all entries in a."). Try running `sum(np.random.choice([-1, 1], size=(n,))) / float(n)` with `n=1000000` to see that skew is small and can be both positive/negative for different runs.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the random number gnerator:

```
np.count_nonzero(np.random.randint(2, size=(1000000,)))
Out[201]: 499522
```

you can do a simple bit of arithmetic to transform 0, 1 to -1, 1

```
np.random.randint(2, size=(10,))*2-1
Out[202]: array([ 1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1])
```